# ffmpeg: convert mjpeg fifo into mp4 stream - on the fly- to render in chromium

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, video-conversion, mjpeg, fifo

I have a mjpeg stream in a fifo (comes from gphoto2 --capture-movie) and I want to play that stream in chromium. 
To capture the mjpeg stream I use:

```
gphoto2 --capture-movie --stdout> fifo.mjpg
```

Now I'm having hard times to figure out how to convert that stream into something I can play in chromium (e.g. video-tag or via javascript).

I have tried to use ffmpeg to convert the stream using the following command

```
gphoto2 --capture-movie --stdout> fifo.mjpg & ffmpeg -i fifo.mjpg -vcodec h264 -acodec copy test.mp4 </dev/null
```

but that produced an corrupt mp4 file. 
I think I somehow need to redirect the output of ffmpeg into a second fifo. Bu I have no idea how to do that. could not find anything in the manual of ffmpeg.
thanks for your help.